# How to create a URL object that points to an hdfs location?

Tags: java, hadoop, url, hdfs

I need to access an `HDFS` location using a `java.net.URL` object. is this possible? If so, then how do I create the URL object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code for getting URI or URL object.

URI uri = URI.create ("hdfs://host: port/file path");

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Hadoop Path object, you can call `Path.toURI().toURL()`.

e.g. `new Path("hdfs://nn1:8020/home/bob/data").toUri().toURL()`

That's pretty convoluted if you don't have a `Path` to hand, but if you do: the best way.

Note that URLs are expensive as some operations on them do DNS lookups. do try and use URIs wherever you can.